# Concat single Quote(') with String in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

At mssql I want concat ' and 1 string

**Example:** `Concat ('My name',''')`

**Ouput :** My name'

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has `||` as concatenation operator, while some products have a `concat()` function.

Comment: Simply: `'My name' || ''''`. I.e. double the single quote inside a string literal.

Answer (score 9):

Or you can use '+':

```
select 'My Name'+''''
```

Answer (score 8):

**Double-up** the single quote character

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('My name','''')
```

**Ouput:**

```
My name'
```